# pyuic from PyQT doesn't consider custom slots

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I can't figure out why my custom slots that I created in the QT creator are not in the transformed python file. Basically **pyuic** doesn't take the `.cpp` file into consideration. Any changes made there are not in the later `.py` file.

For instance my `.cpp` file shows this part:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                       "Open xls File", ".", "xls files (*.xls)" );
    if ( fileName.isEmpty() )
      return;

    QFile file( fileName );
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
       return;
}
```

However the python file doesn't call this class or anything that is in the `.cpp` file.

My python file looks like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(486, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 100, 22))
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 121, 22))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 90, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 40, 211, 27))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.lineEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 90, 211, 27))
        self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 200, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 130, 211, 91))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 130, 91, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 486, 27))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        MainWindow.insertToolBarBreak(self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit.setEnabled)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit2.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit2.setEnabled)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.pushButton.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.pushButton.setEnabled)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Single SMS"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS to Contacts"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add .xls"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send it!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Message Text"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does anyone knows a solution for this? Is there a way to translate the whole project into python and not just the `.ui` file?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: No - pyuic only converts the .ui file. Also, there are no third-party tools that can translate arbitrary C++ code into python code. I suggest you just learn how to do the porting yourself (it's not particularly difficult).

Answer (score 0):

This was too long for a comment:

There is no way to "translate the whole project into python". The Qt Designer generates a .ui file, which you then convert to a .py file via pyuic or a C++ file via uic. Then you have to write the corresponding "logic" code that instantiates your UI file, as you (or someone) did in C++; you have to do same in Python.

However, manually translating the C++ logic file to Python is usually relatively straightforward for 90% of the code, then the last 10% can be a major headache :) It really depends on what your C++ does.

Give it a shot, and if you run into any issues, I suggest you modify your question to ask specifically about those issues. Otherwise, you should delete this question.